# How can I fix an AttributeError while loading checkpoint?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, attributeerror

I am working on Project 2 of a course with Udacity (Artificial Intelligence with Python Programming).

I have trained a model and saved it in checkpoint.pth and I want to load the checkpoint.pth so I can rebuild the model .

I have written the code to save checkpoint.pth and also to load checkpoint.

```py
model.class_to_idx = image_datasets['train_dir'].class_to_idx

model.cpu()

checkpoint = {'input_size': 25088,
              'output_size': 102,
              'hidden_layers': 4096,
              'epochs': epochs,
              'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
              'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
              'class_to_index' : model.class_to_idx
             }


torch.save(checkpoint, 'checkpoint.pth')

def load_checkpoint(filepath):
    checkpoint = torch.load(filepath)

    model = checkpoint.Network(checkpoint['input_size'],
                               checkpoint['output_size'],
                               checkpoint['hidden_layers'],
                               checkpoint['epochs'],
                               checkpoint['optimizer'],
                               checkpoint['class_to_index']
                              )
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])

    return model

model = load_checkpoint('checkpoint.pth')
```

While loading checkpoint.pth, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Network'
```

I want successfully load checkpoint.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: With the full code visibile, I think the issues is in the implementation. torch.load will load the information from the dict that has been deserialized to the file. This loads as the original dict object, so in the function, you should expect checkpoint == checkpoint(original definition).

In this instance, I think what you are actually looking to do is calling the load on the file saved as `checkpoint.pth` and the first call might not be necessary.

```
def load_checkpoint(filepath):
    model = torch.load(filepath)
    return model
```

The other possibility is that the nested object must be what the object is called, and then it would be just a small adjustment:

```
def load_checkpoint(filepath):
    checkpoint = torch.load(filepath)
    model = torch.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    return model
```

---

The most likely problem is that you are calling on the Network class, which is not contained within the checkpoint dictionary object.

I can't speak to the actual lesson or other nuances within the lesson, the simplest solution might be to just call the Network class definition with the variables already in the checkpoint dictionary like so:

```
model = Network(checkpoint['input_size'],
                checkpoint['output_size'],
                checkpoint['hidden_layers'],
                checkpoint['epochs'],
                checkpoint['optimizer'],
                checkpoint['class_to_index'])
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])

return model
```

The checkpoint dict may only have the values you expect ('input_size', 'output_size' etc) But this is just the most obvious issue I see.

Comment: I want to load saved 'checkpoint.pth'. I get NameError: name 'Network' is not defined. my code is `def load_checkpoint(filepath):
    checkpoint = torch.load(filepath)
    
    model = Network(checkpoint['input_size'],
                   checkpoint['output_size'],
                   checkpoint['hidden_layers'],
                   checkpoint['epochs'],
                   checkpoint['optimizer'],
                   checkpoint['class_to_index']
                  )
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    
    return model
model = load_checkpoint('checkpoint.pth')`

Comment: In this case, it might be worth trying the second edit which just runs a torch.load(filepath) and then a load_state_dict `def load_checkpoint(filepath):
    checkpoint = torch.load(filepath)
    model = torch.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    return model`

Comment: the cell goes on to the next cell , when i run the cell with code `def load_checkpoint(filepath):
    checkpoint = torch.load(filepath)
    model = torch.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    return model`  does this mean checkpoint.pth has loaded successfully ?

Comment: Potentially, If you are running a full IDE, I would set breakpoints around the return and in the load_checkpoint function to inspect the values contained within each to see if that is the case.

Comment: i am running (in the udacity website) in jupiter notebook on a shared gpu. not on IDE.

Comment: I believe in jupiter (haven't used it in some time) you can step through each step and it should display the contents after each defined step. It might be worth while to break up the step that is processing this function to display the contents to make sure it meets your expectations.

Comment: Yes, I have broken steps in the jupiter notebook. In the other cells the results get displayed . I think, when I implement the cell to save and another cell to load checkpoint.pth , the cells will not return an answer because its only saving or loading the file and not displaying any results. Am I right?

Comment: That would be correct assuming the code you have is the same in the notebook. You could then also test it by trying to output a value of the map or the end-state model.

Comment: The project included adding arg parsers in python window. When i run the command line arguements, I get an error saying saying "python: can't open file 'train.py' [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Does that mean checkpoint has not been loaded properly?